# Rails Associations - Simple Join

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New working with Rails 4 and have a question on associations.

Let's say I have a Car

```
create_table "cars", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.integer  "mechanic_id"

end
```

And I have some users which roles are "Owner" and "Mechanic"

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "role_id"
end
```

Now when I get a list of Cars, I want the names of the Owner and the Mechanic...

I know this sounds easy but i've been banging my head around the associations and not getting anywhere.

I want to display this:

```
name   owner   mechanic
Ferari Paul    James
```

with this schema

```
User
id  first  role
1   Paul   owner
2   James  mechanic

Car
name     owner_id  mechanic_id
Ferrari  1          2
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two associations to the same model. So in your `model/car.rb` write:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :mechanic, class_name: 'User'
end
```

and you can use `car.owner.name` and `car.mechanic.name`.
See [rails guide on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Thanks Martin - your exmaple + 2.10 from your link really helped!